# How to Access Data With in XMLHTTPRequest onload Function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an XML Request and an onload function to handle the data I receive from it. I understand this is an asynchronous function so if I try to access the arrays it populates outside of it, I will just return nothing, but I am wondering how I could wait for the function to complete therefore have access to the populated array. I have included a very dumbed down version of my code below

```
xhr.open("get", "url");
xhr.send(requestBody);
xhr.onload = function() {
  //populate barData[] with xhr.responseText
   }

//Trying to Access barData[] outside of the onload function
console.log(barData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following approach:

```
xhr.open("get", "url" , false);
xhr.send(requestBody);
xhr.onload = function() {
  //populate barData[] with xhr.responseText
}

console.log(barData)
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The function is still asynchronous so the console.log will execute before barData can be populated.